# Inserting an array based off checkboxes into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Been working on a school assignment to make a webform for entering books into a database.  I'm stuck on a part where I need to insert the book category into the databases book_categories table.  The table only consists of isbn and categoryid.  Inserting the book to the books table was no issue, I think it has to do with inserting an array into the database, while the isbn stays the same (the user can select more than one category).

I'll first post the part that I think is most relevant, and then I'll paste my entire code.  I will say that I know the sql query is correct since I can sub out the variables for real values and it will insert into the database.

```
foreach ($book_categories as $categoryid) {

            $sql3=file_get_contents('setCategory.sql');

            $params2 = array(
            'isbn' => $isbn,
            'category' => $categoryid);

            $statement2=$database->prepare($sql3);
            $statement2->execute($params2);
            }
```

full code

```
 <?php

    // Create and include a configuration file with the database connection
    include('config.php');
    // Get an associative array of categories from the database
    $sql=file_get_contents('category.sql');


    $statement=$database->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();

    $categories = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



    // Get type of form either add or edit from the URL (ex. form.php?action=add)
    $action=$_GET['action'];

    // If form submitted    
        // if the type of form specified in the URL is add
            // Get variables from the form submitted using $_POST
            // Insert the book into the database
            // Set the categories of the book in the database

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
                $title = $_POST['book-title'];
                $book_categories = $_POST['book-category'];
                $author = $_POST['book-author'];
                $price = $_POST['book-price'];

                $sql2=file_get_contents('insertBook.sql');

                $params = array(
                'isbn' => $isbn,
                'author' => $author,
                'title' => $title,
                'price' => $price
            );

                $statement2=$database->prepare($sql2);
                $statement2->execute($params);



                foreach ($book_categories as $categoryid) {

                $sql3=file_get_contents('setCategory.sql');

                $params2 = array(
                'isbn' => $isbn,
                'category' => $categoryid);

                $statement2=$database->prepare($sql3);
                $statement2->execute($params2);
                }

                header('location: index.php');
                die();
            }


        // Redirect to book listing page


    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Add New Book</title>
        <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
        <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <h1>Add New Book</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label>ISBN:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="isbn" class="textbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label>Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="book-title" class="textbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label>Category:</label>
                    <?php 
                    foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
                    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="book-category[]" value=<?php $category['categoryid'] ?> /><span class="radio-label"><?php echo $category['name'] ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label>Author</label>
                    <input type="text" name="book-author" class="textbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label>Price:</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="book-price" class="textbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" />&nbsp;
                    <input type="reset" class="button" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Incidentally, I think ISBN is a poor choice for a PRIMARY KEY. My own view is PRIMARY KEYs should have no meaning beyond the scope of the data base.

Comment: I agree, but this is a school project and the teacher decided to use ISBN as a primary key, so I have to run with it.